# Halloweenmath package collides with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, robust-commands

Recently I am making some handouts, and I want to use the `halloweenmath` package in my handouts. Problems occur when I tag some equation with symbols in the package (e.g. `\mathwitch` and the like) and want to cross-reference these "Halloween-tagged" equations: A lot of errors occur.

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath, hyperref, halloweenmath}

...

\begin{equation} \label{mathwitch}
    R(z) = \sum_{i=1}^q R_i(z) \prod_{j\ne i} (z-\lambda_j)^{k_j}. \tag{$\mathwitch$}
\end{equation}

Putting $z = \lambda_i$ into (\ref{mathwitch}), we find out that ...
```

I have tried to use the symbols in the package as a tag of my equations *without* cross-referencing it, and everything looks fine, so I think the problem lies in the cross-referencing. Then I don't know how to continue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands in `halloweenmath` are not robust, but you can make robust the ones you use in moving argument contexts. Or, for just a single application,

```
\tag{$\protect\mathwitch$}
```

But probably it's better to follow the first strategy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,halloweenmath,hyperref}

\MakeRobust{\mathwitch}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{mathwitch}
    R(z) = \sum_{i=1}^q R_i(z) \prod_{j\ne i} (z-\lambda_j)^{k_j}. \tag{$\mathwitch$}
\end{equation}

Putting $z = \lambda_i$ into \eqref{mathwitch}, we find out that ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Better use `\eqref{<label>}` instead of `(\ref{<label>})`.